# CRC-16-IBM, Reversed 0xA001, Little Endian (DCBA) Implementation

Tags: crc

### Background

I need to implement this algorithm in Node.js, but after searching everywhere I can't find an implementation.

### Code

My first approach was reviewed by a member of StackOverflow and was considered correct:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060262/crc-16-ibm-implementation-js-not-working

However, it didn't work with the test vectors. So at this point I am assuming that I missed or miss interpreted something and that I implemented the wrong algorithm.

### Questions

1. Where can I find an implementation of CRC-16-IBM, Reversed 0xA001, Little Endian (DCBA) ?
2. Is there a way to know given N test vectors which algorithm is being used to create the CRC?

PS: if it is in Javascript, perfect, if not, I can convert it.

---

Test message:

> 00000000000000C1080500000164880D438001014CC5F918ACC14200000000000000F00301F00002B60000430E8B000000000164880C68C000014CC5F918ACC14200000000000000000301F00102B60000430E97000000000164880CA35800014CC5F918ACC14200000000000000000301F00102B60000430E99000000000164880CDDF000014CC5F918ACC14200000000000000000301F00102B60000430E99000000000164880D188800014CC5F918ACC14200000000000000000301F00102B60000430E98000005**00008DC5**

CRC for this message:

00008DC5

Comment: The relation to crypto is so thin as to be invisible..

Comment: I thought that CRC16 was a crypto checksum (https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/cryptographic-checksum). Am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold as off-topic because it is not about cryptography as defined in our help center. **As a heads-up:** Cyclic Redundancy Check codes are used for error-detection and correction. They are not related to cryptography because CRCs are easily reversible functions... in contrast to (for example) cryptographic hash functions (like SHA-256).

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: as a rule, if the whole difficulty preventing computing the right value is the algorithm, then it is not cryptography. In cryptography-as-a-science, ever since [Kerchoff's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) (actually the second principle in the [original French text of 1883](http://www.bibnum.education.fr/sites/default/files/kerckhoffs-texte.pdf#page=8)), there's always a key, and it always has a secret component.

Comment: @fgrieu Ah, so if my problem doesn't include a key, I should not post it here, correct? Thanks for explaining !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRC-16 polynomial `0xCD83` will produce the byte-swapped checksum of your data. It is implemented in the following C++ routine:

```
uint16_t crc16(uint16_t state, uint8_t byte) {
  uint16_t mask;
  uint16_t crc = state ^ uint16_t(byte);
  for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
    mask = -(crc & uint16_t(1));
    crc = (crc >> 1) ^ (mask & uint16_t(0xCD83));
  }
  return crc;
}
```

If you initialize `state=0` and feed this routine your test vector

```
state = crc(state, data[i]);
```

Then after processing the `state` will equal `0xC58D` which is the byte-swapped checksum that you wanted.

There is no 16-bit polynomial that will produce the checksum with the other byte ordering (`0x8DC5`).

Comment: Since according to @e-sushi, CRCs are easily reversible, is there a way, that given any test vector, to find out the CRC algorithm used to compute it?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Yes: [Berlekamp-Massey](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiizdKF2aPcAhUB3xoKHbO-CUIQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBerlekamp%25E2%2580%2593Massey_algorithm&usg=AOvVaw0GShf8drxaEt7qU0xb-1cI). If we only care about specific length(s) of messages; there's a different [method](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32704/how-can-i-figure-out-a-hash-algorithm/32712#32712) working for any affine transformation (including CRCs with whatever bogus byte order and variant the implementor may have used).

Comment: This answer is wrong for two reasons: First you included the expected CRC into the message. Second: With your construction you cannot reproduce the expected CRC for the other given test vector. I did not found any CRC-16 algorithm which can do this.